# CompletableFuture in Java, code that gets responses from different websites using HttpClient in Java. What can I do better?

Tags: java, asynchronous

I have a static list of Strings (website urls), I am trying to connect to them and get responses, in syncRequests method, I am using HttpClient in synchronous manner, in asyncRequests method, I am using HttpClient in asynchronous manner. I am seeing some time differences between syncRequests and asyncRequests time, but I have a hunch I maybe doing something wrong or I can do something better.

Fellow stackexchange users, kindly review my code and let me know any changes or improvements that I can make.

Syntax wise I can make some changes related to modularizing the code, but what I want to understand is, improvements in terms of performance related to Completable Future and HttpClient. Below code is sort of a POC to understand CompletableFuture and check for any performance gains on response related processing.

Below is my code.

Thanks in advance.

`

```
    public class ProcessingList {

    static List<String> urls = Arrays.asList("https://www.google.com", "https://www.reddit.com", "https://www.yahoo.co.in", "https://www.hackerrank.com", "https://devrant.com",
            "https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.net.http/java/net/http/HttpClient.html",
            "https://bing.com", "https://xkcd.com", "https://www.facebook.com", "https://www.amazon.co.in",
            "https://www.flipkart.com");

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        long start = System.currentTimeMillis();

        List<String> resp1 = syncRequests();

        System.out.println("time taken 1:" + (System.currentTimeMillis() - start));

        start = System.currentTimeMillis();

        List<String> resp2 = asyncRequests();

        System.out.println("time taken 1:" + (System.currentTimeMillis() - start));
    }

    private static List<String> syncRequests() {
        HttpClient client = HttpClient.newBuilder()
                .followRedirects(HttpClient.Redirect.NORMAL)
                .version(HttpClient.Version.HTTP_2)
                .build();

        return urls.stream().map(url -> {
            try {
                HttpRequest request = HttpRequest.newBuilder().uri(new URI(url)).build();
                HttpResponse<String> resp = client.send(request, HttpResponse.BodyHandlers.ofString());
                return resp.body();
            } catch (URISyntaxException | InterruptedException | IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            return "";
        }).collect(Collectors.toList());//.forEach(System.out::println);
    }

    private static List<String> asyncRequests() {

        List<CompletableFuture<String>> list = new ArrayList<>();
        List<String> responses = new ArrayList<>();
        ExecutorService service1 = Executors.newCachedThreadPool();
        ExecutorService service2 = Executors.newCachedThreadPool();

        HttpClient client = HttpClient.newBuilder()
                .followRedirects(HttpClient.Redirect.NORMAL)
                .version(HttpClient.Version.HTTP_2)
                .build();

        urls.parallelStream().forEach(url -> {
            try {
                HttpRequest request = HttpRequest.newBuilder().uri(new URI(url)).build();
                list.add(
                        client
                                .sendAsync(request, HttpResponse.BodyHandlers.ofString())
                                .thenApplyAsync(HttpResponse::body, service1)
                                .whenCompleteAsync((resp, err) -> {
                                    responses.add(resp);
                                }, service2)
                );
            } catch (URISyntaxException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

        });

        list.forEach(cf -> {
            responses.add(cf.join());
        });

        service1.shutdown();
        service2.shutdown();

        return responses;
    }
```

`